# Why is applying a function to slices of data.frame faster?

Tags: r

I had a string vectors of 800k elements to match against a dictionary of 9k. I noticed that that the execution of the `match` function took significantly less (minutes against more than an hour) if I sliced the data.frame. Why?

I was able to replicate the situation with a smaller n example. The difference is not that significant in this case, but still, it is not clear why slicing is faster. So what would be the best optimization strategy?

```
data <- data.frame(inputA = sample(LETTERS, 80000, replace = T),
                   inputB = sample(LETTERS, 80000, replace = T),
                   output = NA,
                   stringsAsFactors = F)

system.time(
  data$output <- sapply(data$inputA, FUN = function(x) sum(x %in% data$inputB))
)

# user  system elapsed 
# 20.365  18.960  38.690 

require(ggplot2)
chunks <- cut_number(1:nrow(data), 9, labels = F)
system.time(
  for(c in 1:9) {
    data$output[chunks == c] <- sapply(data$inputA[chunks == c], FUN = function(x) sum(x %in% data$inputB))
  }
)

# user  system elapsed 
# 18.596  18.352  37.705
```

Comment: How about `sapply(unique(data$inputA), function(x) as.integer(x %in% unique(data$inputB)))` since you have highly repetitive values, at least in the example. Or even `intersect(data$inputA, data$inputB)`

Comment: depending on your actual setup, the `fastmatch` package might help speed things up as well.

Comment: In both cases, your code produces a vector of 1s. Are you trying to obtain frequency distributions of each combination of `inputA` and `inputB`, or are you trying to obtain frequency distributions for all `inputA` in `inputB`, where the output is a data frame with columns `inputA` and the count of occurrences?

Answer (score 0):

If the objective is to obtain frequencies of `inputA` for each item in `inputB`, then `data.table()` with an index will perform faster than a solution with `sapply()` and `cut()`.

```
library(data.table)

data <- data.table(inputA = sample(LETTERS, 80000, replace = T),
                   inputB = sample(LETTERS, 80000, replace = T),
                   count = rep(1,80000),
                   stringsAsFactors = F)
setkey(data,inputA)

system.time(
     output <- data[inputA %in% inputB,sum(count),by=inputA]
)
head(output)
```

...and the output:

```
> system.time(
+      output <- data[inputA %in% inputB,sum(count),by=inputA]
+ )
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0 
> head(output)
   inputA   V1
1:      A 3141
2:      B 3050
3:      C 2995
4:      D 2996
5:      E 3082
6:      F 3118
>
```